# Is there a use case for using ng-content with a component selector over a component tag?

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

The way I see it - an ng-content tag with a component selector is the same thing as writing the component tag itself. For example, a project I'm doing some tasks for uses this:

```
<div class="sidebar-style"
             [ngClass]="{
                            'sidebar-hidden': !showSidebar
                        }">
            <ng-content select="car-sidebar"></ng-content>   <-------this
        </div>
```

And I don't understand, why would that code be chosen over this:

```
<div class="sidebar-style"
             [ngClass]="{
                            'sidebar-hidden': !showSidebar
                        }">
            <car-sidebar></car-sidebar> <-----is the same as this
        </div>
```

Are there any reasons/use cases where the ng-content should be used instead of the component tag itself?

Answer (score 0):

They are two different elements, with a component tag you render that component inside some other parent component. You can't put any text between a component tag if it doesn't have an  `<ng-content></ng-content>` inside its HTML

i.e 
`<car-sidebar>Some Test Here </car-sidebar>` wont display any text if it doesnt have 
`<ng-content></ng-content>` in its (car-sidebar.component.html) file

Answer (score 0):

Lets say we have two different components as you described

Parent1:

```
<div class="sidebar-style"
    <ng-content select="car-sidebar"></ng-content>   <-------this
</div>
```

Parent2:

```
<div class="sidebar-style"
    <car-sidebar></car-sidebar> <-----is the same as this
</div>
```

Usage examples:

```
<Parent1>
    <p>some random unnecessary text</p>
    <car-sidebar aParameter=[aValue]></car-sidebar>
</Parent1>
```

will output to

```
<Parent1>
    <p>some random unnecessary text</p>
    <car-sidebar aParameter=[aValue]></car-sidebar>
</Parent1>
```

but

```
<Parent2>
    <p>some random unnecessary text</p>
    <car-sidebar aParameter=[aValue]></car-sidebar>
</Parent2>
```

will output to

```
<Parent2>
    <car-sidebar></car-sidebar> <-----is the same as this
</Parent2>
```